# How to connect a web app to a gamefleet instance?

Tags: websocket, network-programming, amazon-gamelift

I've gone over the intro amazon gamelift tutorial, and something I'm trying to understand is how a web app transitions from communicating with the app backend to a gamelift instance.

For example the following call can tell the backend that an [available session exists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/apireference/API_SearchGameSessions.html), and returns a list of IP addresses (as well as other information.) Is it a matter of returning that desired IP to the client, and transitioning to a websocket connection with that IP, or are there more authentication details I'm completely missing, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the client side SDK for this is still only available in C#:
https://forums.awsgametech.com/t/javascript-as-a-game-client-for-a-gamelift-server/7679/6

If I end up porting this to JS, I'll edit this comment to point to a public repository.